# MySQL regex query case insensitive

Tags: mysql

In my table I have firstname and last name.  Few names are upper case ( ABRAHAM ), few names are lower case (abraham), few names are character starting with ucword (Abraham).

So when i am doing the where condition using REGEXP '^[abc]', I am not getting proper records.  How to change the names to lower case and use SELECT QUERY.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE cus_name REGEXP '^[abc]';
```

This is my query, works fine if the records are lower case, but my records are intermediate ,my all cus name are not lower case , all the names are like ucword.

So for this above query am not getting proper records display.

Comment: What actual issue are you trying to solve? `REGEXP` is almost always a wrong solution.

Comment: and also my above regexp query displaying starting with U,V,W, ALL ALPHABETS, ABOVE REGEXP NOT WORKING

Comment: And also i want to search the name starting with a or b or c,

Comment: @zerkms I am curious, why is REGEXP almost always a wrong solution?

Comment: @Jonathan I was young and wrong 8 years ago :-) It's not a wrong solution :-P

Comment: @zerkms Oh! Haha I should have definitely checked the date, thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you should query your database making sure that the names are lowered, suppose that name is the name you whish to find out, and in your application you've lowered it like 'abraham', now your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE LOWER(cus_name) = name
```

Since i dont know what language you use, I've just placed name, but make sure that this is lowered and you should retrieve Abraham, ABRAHAM or any variation of the name!

Hepe it helps!

Comment: REGEXP '^[[:<:]]b.*[[:>:]]' this rendering the records name starting with b but if i add or condition then it displaying REGEXP '^[[:<:]]b.*|c.*[[:>:]]' all records , that is starting with what ever like f,t,h,u but as per my condition it should render only starts with b and c character names,

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE LOWER(cus_name) REGEXP '^[abc]';
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know since when, but nowadays MySql REGEXP is case insensitive.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

[image]

Comment: as mysql typical it's a mess, sometimes it's sensitive sometimes not.
It looks like a variety of factors play in, collation, type, version number. Maybe a random number somewhere hidden.
After all they want you to buy oracle :)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0 you can use the "regexp_like" passing the "matching_type" equals to "c" for case sensitive, or "i" for case insensitive matching.

```
select id, name
from client
where regexp_like(name, '^[a-z]', 'c');
```

That SQL will return all clients which have the name with lower case starting.

You can search more here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regexp to search for names starting with a specific string or character.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE cus_name LIKE 'abc%' ;
```

% is wildcard char. The search is case insensitive unless you set the binary attribute for column cus_name or you use the binary operator

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE BINARY cus_name LIKE 'abc%' ;
```

Comment: your query searches for names starting with the string 'abc' something very different from OP's query which searches for names beginning with either 'a' or 'b' or 'c'.

Comment: I assumed the user was trying to build a "search as you type" field/tool.

Answer (score 0):

A few valid options already presented, but here's one more with just regex:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE cus_name REGEXP '^[abcABC]';
```