# Is this a valid solution/ use of MySQL REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex

Is the following code a valid solution to the problem detailed below? I found a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993272/mysql-regex-query-case-insensitive#comment4275556_3993272) that suggested otherwise. (I'd have replied to his comment but I'm a new user.)

I need to query a WordPress database for posts that contain a particular word. Many times. If I just used the word itself each search would return too many results. But with enough format requirements I should be able to nail the correct post every time. Hence regular expressions.

The code works, btw. Just concerned that "REGEXP is almost always a wrong solution".

Is that true? Why?

Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT ID, 
post_title 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_title REGEXP '[[.quotation-mark.]][[:blank:]]?([[:alnum:]]{3}[[:blank:]]?)?[[:<:]]{$filename}[[:>:]][[:blank:]]?[[.quotation-mark.]]'";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: It ultimately depends on what you are using the `REGEXP` for. If you shared more about your query then we could better advise.

Comment: You are looking for rather odd strings like `? x67` ?  You could very efficiently look for the "word" `x67` via a `FULLTEXT` index.